# Visual C# Label Format not showing leading zeroes in seconds field

Tags: c#

I am modifying a program using Visual Studio 2015 and have created a chart, with the label formatting specified by:

this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "mm:ss";

However, the chart appears without leading zeroes on some values.  See below; "3:07" is displayed as "3:7", etc.  I am no c# wizard, so thanks in advance for any help!

```
        public string makeCharLabel(double chartTime)
    {
        string labelBuild;
        labelBuild = (((int)(chartTime)) - ((int)(chartTime / 60) * 60)).ToString();
        if (labelBuild == "0")
        {
            labelBuild = "00";
        }
        labelBuild = ((int)(chartTime/60)).ToString() + ":" + labelBuild;

        return labelBuild;
    }

        {
        double chartIncrement;
      //  holdInterval = 150;
      //  NumberOfCycles = 3;
        chartIncrement = 0;
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Series[1].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Series[2].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Series[3].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Series[3].BorderWidth = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = AppliedPressure / 4;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -2 * AppliedPressure / 4;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 6 * AppliedPressure / 4;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "mm:ss";

        int chartcounter;


        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1* AppliedPressure/4);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
        chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;


        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);

        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);

        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);



        for (chartcounter = 0; chartcounter < NumberOfCycles; chartcounter++)
        {
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;
            this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
            chartIncrement = chartIncrement + holdInterval / 4;

            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 4 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);

            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 6 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 2 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 6 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);

            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 5 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 5 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 5 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 5 * AppliedPressure / 4);
            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
            this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);

        }

        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), -1 * AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(makeCharLabel(chartIncrement), 0);

        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY("", 0);

        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", AppliedPressure / 4);
        this.chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddXY("", 0);

        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);
        this.chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddXY("", 0);


    }
```

[image]

Comment: What chart tool are you using?  What is the type of `chart1` ? `mm:ss` is correct if `.Format` uses standard C# TimeSpan or DateTime formatting, but as it isn't working, it's likely that the control has non-standard format specifications.

Comment: ChartType is StackedColumn for three series, plus a StepLine for one additional.

Comment: Looks like a snake game.  Anyway, always helpful to give us enough code and data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure what "chart tool" I am using.  Is it System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart ?

Comment: @LarsTech, Code is added.  The values for the two commented lines are normally from another section of the code.

Comment: What's an acceptable value for AppliedPressure?  Need the makeCharLabel function.

Comment: @LarsTech , My mistake.   AppliedPressure is 200 in the sample.

Comment: @LarsTech, Series4 is the StepLine, the others are StackedColumn

Comment: Like I said, need the makeCharLabel function.

Comment: Hi @LarsTech,  I have added some more code for the CharLabel Function, which I would not have known existed without your help.

Comment: Looks like you add the x-values as strings. This means that you can't use any numeric or date/time formatting. - A common mistake most of the time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your labels are strings, formatting wouldn't affect them.  You can fix your makeCharLabel to do the formatting properly when constructing the string:

```
public string makeCharLabel(double chartTime) {
  int seconds = (((int)(chartTime)) - ((int)(chartTime / 60) * 60));
  int minutes = ((int)(chartTime / 60));
  return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: Adding those values as times would be much better than fiddling with the labels as the actual numbers then would not be lost and can be used in various ways..

Comment: @TaW You would probably have to post that as an answer — you have more experience at charts than I do.  My attempts at a DateTime series doesn't produce the same chart appearance.

Comment: Thanks for your help!